# Magic __get in php

Tags: php

i need help about this below:

i understand the code but i do not understand the output of the last line

why the output is `b,A,B` and not `A,b,B`  ?

```
class magic{

    public $a = "A";    
    protected $b = array("a" => "A", "b" => "B","c" => "C");
    protected $c = array(1,2,3);


    public function __get($name){
        echo "$name,";
        return $this -> b[$name];
    }

}

$m = new magic();

echo $m->a;
// A
// because $a is public

echo $m->b;
// b,B
// because $b is protected

echo $m->a.",".$m->b; 
// b,A,B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your echoing the name in your `__get()` method, this will output the value straight away, but return the value of the variable to display later.

If you change the routine to...

```
public function __get($name){
    //echo "$name,";
    return "$name,".$this -> b[$name];
}
```

Your output becomes - `A,b,B`